# Is there a hotkey (or is it possible to set one) for hiding/dismissing the warnings in the iOS simulator for React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

When repetitive warnings come up like "make your javascript faster" or "your debug console is in the background", I'm getting really tired of clicking and "dismiss all" to get them out of the way...

Is there someway to make this part of development smoother, like by dismissing with a hotkey?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To disable warnings in iOS simulator you just have to do some changes in your localhost command which you can find in AppDelegate.m

Change this:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

to:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=false"];
```

The only change which is processed in above command is the dev parameter, the dev parameter value is turned to false.

Cheers :)